# Retorno de Funcionário Igual

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte código

```
$sql = "
        SELECT 
            c.*, 
            cl.razaosocial, 
            cl.idCliente 
        FROM 
            chamada as c, 
            cliente as cl 
        WHERE 
            c.idCliente = cl.idCliente";
$consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();

foreach($consulta as &$valor)
{
    $this->db->where('idFuncionario', $valor->idFuncionario);
    if($this->db->get('funcionario')->row('nome'))
    {
        $valor->funcionarioNome = $this->db->get('funcionario')->row('nome');
    }
    else 
    {
        $valor->funcionarioNome = "";   
    }
}

return $consulta;
```

Ele retorna no `$valor->funcionarioNome` sempre o mesmo nome.

O que teria de errado ali?

Pensei em tentar fazer este SQL, ele só exibe os que estão setados os funcionários na chamada, mas há chamadas em "aberto" sem funcionários eleito ainda.

```
SELECT c.*, f.nome as nomeFuncionario, f.idFuncionario, cl.razaosocial, cl.idCliente FROM chamada as c, cliente as cl, funcionario as f WHERE c.idCliente = cl.idCliente AND c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario GROUP BY c.idFuncionario
```

[image: Esta imagem representa o erro. Notem que por mais que o ID funcionario seja diferente, ele imprime nomes iguais...]

Comment: `$valor` deve ser um array de funcionarios ou apenas uma?

Comment: Apenas um funcionario, na verdade, quero só o nome dele...

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, descreva o que deseja fazer. Só olhando o ´código não ele não 'demonstra' intenção nehuma.

Comment: Adicionei as informações

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer adicionar o nome do funcionário no retorno da consulta não é mais fácil buscá-lo no `SELECT`?

Acredito que seu `idFuncionario` fica na tabela `Chamada`, então:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.*, 
               cl.razaosocial, 
               cl.idCliente,
               f.nome as funcionarioNome
            FROM chamada as c
            INNER JOIN cliente as cl on c.idCliente = cl.idCliente
            LEFT JOIN funcionario as f on c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario ";
```

Coloquei `LEFT JOIN` por parecer que nem sempre você tem o funcionário.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN cliente as cl on c.idCliente = cl.idCliente

Comment: @AndréBaill Perdão, eu esqueci uma vírgula antes do `INNER` da uma olhada

Comment: Sim, pelo SELECT deu certo. Consegui exibir os nomes corretamente. Agradeço pela ajuda... @maicon-carraro

Comment: @AndréBaill Se resolveu seu problema, por favor marque a resposta como a solução. :)